# Translate application at runtime

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, translation

Is there a solution to translate the text of a program at runtime?

I couldn't find anything about this topic by researching the internet, only websites and applications to translate text showed up.

By that I mean to have a compiled exe with a GUI in language xyz which is not mine and I do not have access to the source code.
Now I would like to alter the Text on the GUI by a translated version of the text.

The exe itself is a regular program with no translation options added to it.

For example I have a chinese application but I cannot read chinese. Now I'd like to translate that application into english, at runtime if possible.

The only other method that comes to my mind would be to take screenshots, use an OCR to get the text and a translater to translate the text but this would take forever to do for more complex applications.

Comment: Please read [ask] and elaborate on what you mean _exactly_ by "translate the text of a program at runtime". You can start at [MSDN: Globalizing and Localizing .NET Framework Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6270d0z(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Are you trying to create a program with a user interface (UI) that supports multiple spoken languages?

Comment: I added more detail to it, this question is about applications I have no access to.

Answer (score 0):

If your chinese application supports this, you can create a satellite assembly. See here for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht.aspx
You can use a tool like ILSpy to check which resources are included and possible to translate.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.weglot.com/ provides run-time translation.